# How to customize PNG images in SVG tag?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, png

I am trying to change the colour of the png image in the SVG tag. I have PNG's of transparent types. I need to customize the colours in the PNG according to the colour selected by the user. As there are features where you can change the colours in different parts. So How this can be done? Is there anyone who could help me?

```
  <HoodieSvg
    backgound="red"
    width="800"
    height="800">
    <image href={lights} width="400" height="400" fill="#000"/>
    <image href={model} width="400" height="400" />
    <image href={shadows} width="400" height="400" />
  </HoodieSvg>

import React from 'react'

const HoodieSvg = (props) => {

return (
  <svg
    {...props}
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    {props.children}
  </svg>
)
}

 export default HoodieSvg
```

Comment: Change it HOW?.

Comment: I have updated the statement...please check @Paulie_D

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot change the colors of *parts* of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike regular SVG elements, I don't think it's possible to change the color of a PNG image inside a svg tag. According to the Mozilla doc, the svg/image attributes are x, y, width and height

Comment: I have PNG's of transparent types. I need to customize the colours in the PNG according to colour selected by the client. As there are more features where you can change the colours in different parts. So How this can be done?

Comment: Then add a SVG rect with a color fill and place your PNG file on top of it

Comment: How to change multiple colours over a png...For Ex: If we need to colour hood or sleeves with a different colour?

Comment: You can do that with regular SVG elements where you can apply a stroke color, a fill color or gradient but I don't think it's possible with png.

Comment: Is there a better solution than this... Are there any libraries to put image layer over another image... Like the one we do in photoshop... Thanks @HermitCrab